# Regex to match part of string, when match does not contain a specific string - PCRE grep

Tags: regex, grep, replace, textwrangler

I'm using TextWrangler grep to perform find/replace on multiple files and have run into a wall with the last find/replace I need to perform. I need to match any text between `">` and the first instance of a `<br />` in a line but the match cannot contain the character sequence [xcol]. The regex flavor is Perl-Compatible (PCRE) so lookbehind needs to be fixed-length.

Example Text to Search:

```
<p class="x03">FooBar<br />Bar</p>
<p class="x03">FooBar [xcol]<br />Bar</p>
<p class="x06">Hello World<br />[xcol]foo[xcol]bar<br /></p>
<p class="x07">Hello World[xcol]<br />[xcol]foo[xcol]bar<br /></p>
```

Desired behavior of regex:
1st Line **match** `">`FooBar`<br />`
2nd Line **no match**
3rd Line **match** `">`Hello World`<br />`
4th Line **no match**

The text between `">` and the `<br />` will be captured in a group to be used with the replace function. The closest I got was using the following regex with negative lookahead, but this will not match the 3rd line as desired:

```
">((?!.*?\[xcol]).*?)<br />
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
">((?!\[xcol]).)*<br\s*/>
```

A (short) explanation:

```
">               # match '">'
(                # start group 1
  (?!\[xcol]).   #   if '[xcol]' can't be seen ahead, match any character (except line breaks)
)                # end group 1
*                # repeat group 1 zero or more times
<br\s*/>         # match '<br />'
```

If you need to match line breaks for `.` as well, either enable DOT-ALL (add `(?s)` before the `.`) or replace the `.` with something like `[\s\S]`

Comment: @lxbrg, you're welcome. You were damn close to the solution yourself! :)